# Derivation of the pdf for two degrees of freedom of chi squared

Tags: statistics, density-function, chi-squared

I am studying [this derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution#Derivation_of_the_pdf_for_two_degrees_of_freedom), which makes the following statements:

$$ f(x,y)= \frac{1}{2\pi}(x,y) ^\frac{-1}{2} e^{-\frac{x+y}{2}}$$
$$A= xy $$
$$B=x+y$$
$$ x=\frac{B+\sqrt{B^2-4A}}{2}$$
$$ y=\frac{B-\sqrt{B^2-4A}}{2}$$

What I don't understand is this part:

Given $f(B)=2\times\frac{e^{-\frac{B}{2}}}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{B^2}{4}}A^{-\frac{1}{2}}(B^2-4A)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dA$, let $ A=\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2(t)$.

Then $f(B)=2\times\frac{e^{-\frac{B}{2}}}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \, dt$

I can't figure out the exact trigonometric substitution process behind this. How do i prove that  $ A=\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2(t)$ ?

**UPDATE -Nov 4**

Thanks to J.G. for your help. It's actually the process of deriving $ A=\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2(t)$ that I am more curious about because this process is not shown on the Wikipedia link, and I am still at loss on how A is computed in such a way using $sin^2$(t).

**Update - NOV 5**

Thanks again J.G. i have a followup question about using
 $ A=\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2(t)$ to get $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \, dt$.

I got this outcome instead when I substituted A with $ \frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2(t)$  in $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}(B^2-4A)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ $:

$$\frac{2}{B^2sin(t)cos(t)}\ $$

Can you please show the correct process so I will end up with $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \, dt$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF of $B$ is shown to be $\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-B/2}\int_0^{B^2/4}A^{-1/2}(B^2-4A)^{-1/2}dA$, but then that integral needs to be evaluated. The substitution $A=\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2t$ was chosen because in view of $\sin^2t+\cos^2t$ it converts the expression to$$\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-B/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2t\right)^{-1/2}(B^2\cos^2t)^{-1/2}\frac{B^2}{2}\sin t\cos tdt=\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-B/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}dt=\frac12 e^{-B/2}.$$

Let's explore the rationale behind this substitution a bit more. Write $C:=B^2-4A$ so $A+\frac{C}{4}=\frac{B^2}{4}$. that looks a *bit* like $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$, or equivalently $\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2t+\frac{B^2}{4}\cos^2t=\frac{B^2}{4}$. We may as well identify $A$ with one of the terms on the left-hand side; either way, $t$ can be taken to vary from $0$ to $\pi/2$, so that the substitution is monotonic. Choosing $A=\frac{B^2}{4}\sin^2t$ instead of $A=\frac{B^2}{4}\cos^2t$ has the further advantage that $A$ is an increasing function of $t$, which reduces the risk of sign errors when transforming the integral.

Comment: Thanks JG. It's actually the derivation of   A=B^2/4sin^2(t) that I am more curious about because this process is not shown on the Wikipedia link, and I am still at loss on how to prove that.

Comment: @Edville You don't "prove" a substitution; you just try one to see if it helps evaluate the integral.

Comment: What i mean is the rational behind the use of sin^2 and how A  is computed in such a way using sin^2

Comment: @Edville See edit. What you meant was you wanted to *motivate* the substitution.

Comment: Thanks J.G. Can you also please show the process so I can end up with (1)dt, because I tried replacing A with B^2/4sin^2(t) , but I got a different result as shown on my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: @Edville See edit.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your kind support J.G.!